# Почему не виден namespace битрикса?

Tags: php, битрикс, phpstorm

Возникает такая ошибка

> Class 'CHTTP' not found in

Вопрос: почему может быть не виден namespace битрикса и как это исправить?

Comment: Желательно показать код где это возникает или дождаться выхода из отпуска телепатов.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте весь относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос. [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Кода не вижу, по этому возможно CHTTP находится в другом namespace и если вы создаете новый экземляр, то надо указывать "\" перед именем класса:

```
$a = new \CHTTP();
```